# Complex Log, Branchs and contradictions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

just a quick question with the hopes someone may be able to help clarify where my confusion is.

I've been asked to find which equality or conclusion is wrong. we have

$$2Log(2) = Log(2^2) = Log((-2)^2)=2Log(-2)$$

now, the important part of this question i believe is to consider which branch we're on. and so i include the following two definitions from my source material

> **Def:** We define the Arg(z), the principal value of the arguement as
>   $$Arg(z) = \theta \longleftrightarrow |z|(cos \theta + i sin \theta), ~\theta \in [0,2\pi)$$

and

> **Def:** We define the principal branch Log of the log function to be
>   $$Log(z) = log|z| + i arg(z),~ 0 \leq arg(z) < 2\pi$$

Now, $$2Log(-2) = 2\pi i + Log(4)$$
i believe 
But we have to note the use of the Big L, i know we're on the principal branch, from my memory then, for the fact the range is $[0,2\pi)$ then we're on the branch $ z \in [0,\infty)$ specifically. in which case, does that make $2 Log(-1)$ undefined? in which case can i negate that entirely leading to a true equality between the two?

and so i have a better understanding if we were on the branch $z \in (-\infty,0]$ we'd be using $-\pi < arg \leq \pi$ in which case, we wouldnt be using the principal branch (as defined above) of Log(4) since that would be undefined here.

Thanks for the help, Sincerely.

Comment: $\log$ is a group isomorphism $\Bbb{C^* \to C/2i\pi Z}$, thus for $n\in \Bbb{Z}, \log(a^n)=n\log a$ and $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$, but the latter are additions modulo $2i\pi$, a branch is a lift to an analytic function $\log : U\subset \Bbb{C^* \to C}$

Comment: $\log (-1) = i\pi+2i\pi \Bbb{Z},\log 2=\ln 2+2i\pi \Bbb{Z}$, $\log (-1)+\log 2= i\pi + \ln 2+2i\pi \Bbb{Z}$, Concretely $\log z $ is the set of complex numbers such that $z=e^s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to be bothered much about what's happening -- it's not farfetched. The equality $$\log a^b=b\log a$$ fails to remain true whenever $a$ is negative since then LHS is single-valued, finitely valued or infinitely valued (depending on whether $b$ is respectively an integer, a nonintegral rational number, or an irrational number) whereas RHS is *always* multi-valued in an infinite manner. Even at that it's not guaranteed that there are some values on either side that will make the equality true. Consider the case of wanting $$\log(-1)^2=2\log(-1)$$ to be true, for example. Since RHS is $2(iπ+2πik)$ for an arbitrary integer $k,$ we see that there is no $k$ so that $$0=2πi(1+2k),$$ so that in this case the equality is false through and through.

Thus the problem is in the last step where you write $$\log(-2)^2=2\log (-2).$$ This is plain false since in this case LHS has a single value whereas RHS has infinitely many values, for one. This is only true if there is a choice of one of the values on RHS that becomes equal to $\log 4,$ so that we may restrict the equation to such a case, and in that case only is it true.

Comment: Would this be true still if we restricted $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$ ? sorry it's late here at this point and i'm quite tired.
Mostly since with the restriction log(-2) has only a single value, isn't that the point of working on that branch?

Comment: @Vaas As I pointed out in my edited last paragraph. The equality is true only for carefully chosen values of both sides. But as written, it is simply not true.

Comment: out of interest; would you have an example of the carefully chosen values? i'm wondering just what branch they equate on. Also thanks for all your help so far

Comment: @Vaas OK, suppose you want $$\log (-1)^2=2\log(-1),$$ for example, then since RHS is $2(iπ+2πki)=2πi(1+2k),$ for an arbitrary integer $k$ and there's no way this can vanish, in this case we can't even have the equation to be true at all.